# How to make a mouse event for clicks on a masked image [Pygame]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I'm really new to programming and I'm working on a game that is sort of like Cookie Clicker, but with a twist (Mining). It is made in python/pygame. Anyways I have an image of a boulder and I want to add a rock to my inventory in the game every time i click on it.

Someone helped me out setting up the point_collide in my class. I will confess and say I don't fully understand how it works but its supposed to detect if my mouse is on a non-transparent part of my rock image.

I want the game to only give you a rock if your clicking on the NON-transparent parts of the boulder image I have blitted to the middle of the screen.

Short Question: How can I setup the game to register clicks only on my masked image?

PS: I know it'd be better to learn the fundamentals of programming first, but I have learned so much just by diving straight into a project (it keeps me going and alot more fun then reading a book).

Link to code: https://www.refheap.com/88634

The Code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
from datetime import datetime

if (__name__ == "__main__"):

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
pygame.display.set_caption("Miner Click")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((960,600))
width = 960
height = 600

GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BROWN = (84,27,1) 
GREY = (198,198,198)

greenbg = pygame.image.load("greenbg.jpg").convert()
rockbutton = pygame.image.load("rockbutton.png").convert_alpha()
woodbutton = pygame.image.load("woodbutton.png").convert_alpha()

pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
pick = pygame.image.load("pick.png").convert_alpha()
axe = pygame.image.load("axesmall.png").convert_alpha()

rockwidth = 544
rockheight = 274

clicks = 0
wood = 0

stonefont = pygame.font.SysFont("verdana", 29, True)
woodfont = pygame.font.SysFont("verdana", 29, True)
clicktext = stonefont.render('Rock: ' +str(clicks), 2, (GREY))
woodtext = woodfont.render('Wood: ' +str(wood), 2, (BROWN))
boxsize = clicktext.get_rect()
RocksX = 125
WoodX = 113

class Rock(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

def __init__(self, color = BLUE, width = 544, height = 274):
    super(Rock, self ).__init__()

    self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
    self.set_properties()
    self.image.fill(color)

def set_properties(self):
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.origin_x = self.rect.centerx
    self.origin_y = self.rect.centery

def set_position(self, x, y):
    self.rect.x = 250
    self.rect.y = 230

def set_image(self, filename = None):
    if (filename != None):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()

def point_collide(self, point):
    x, y = point
    x -= self.rect.x
    y -= self.rect.y
    try:
        return self.mask.get_at((x,y))
    except IndexError:
        return False

#below is my clueless attempt at getting it to work
def checkForCursorPressed(x,y):
    if pygame.mouse.get_pressed() and pygame.mouse.get_pos() == (x,y):
        clicks+=1

coordfont = pygame.font.SysFont("verdana", 12, True)
rock_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
rock = Rock()
rock.set_image("rock.png")
rock.set_position(width/2, height/2)
rock_group.add(rock)

while True:
    clock.tick(60)
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    screen.blit(greenbg, (0,0))
    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    coords = x,y
    now = datetime.now()
    date = '%s/%s/%s' % (now.month, now.day, now.year)
    label = coordfont.render("Coordinates: "+str(coords), 1, (GREY))
    date = coordfont.render("Date: "+str(date), 1, (GREY))
    screen.blit(date, (650,10))
    screen.blit(label, (790, 10))
    screen.blit(rockbutton, (25,25))
    screen.blit(woodbutton, (25,100))
    clicktext = stonefont.render(' ' +str(clicks), 2, (GREY))
    woodtext = woodfont.render(' ' +str(wood), 2, (BROWN))
    screen.blit(clicktext, [RocksX,38])
    screen.blit(woodtext, [139,WoodX])
    rock_group.draw(screen)
    screen.blit(pick, (x-10,y-50))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           sys.exit()
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE: 
           sys.exit()


        pygame.display.update()

   #in case i need the below again
   #if x>249 and x<(795) and y>210 and y<(484):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking will create a MOUSEBUTTONDOWN event, so you should be able to deal with clicks within your event-processing loop, e.g.:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
       sys.exit()
    elif event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
       sys.exit()
    elif event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        click_position = event.pos
        if rock.point_collide(click_position):
            print('Clicked within the rock')
            clicks += 1
            # Any other events that have to happen
            #   when the rock is clicked
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks! That is what I was looking for :) Although I'm getting an error Line 72 'Rock' object has no attribute 'mask'

Answer (score 0):

I also don't understand how point_collide() works and I get an AttributeError: 'Rock' does not have attribute 'mask'. 
So I would use an other possibility to detect if one clicked on non-transparent parts of the image, using colorkey.

The colorkey defines the transparent color when blitting. In my case it's white:

```
def set_image(self, filename = None):
    ...
    #sets colorkey to white, depends on the image
    self.image.set_colorkey((255,255,255))
```

New version of point_collide():

```
def point_collide(self, point):
   x, y = point
   x -= self.rect.x
   y -= self.rect.y
   #detects if click hits the image
   if 0 <= x < self.image.get_width():
       if 0 <= y < self.image.get_height():
           #detects if color at clicking position != colorkey-color(transparent)
           if self.image.get_at((x,y))[0:3] != self.image.get_colorkey()[0:3]:
               return True
   return False
```

How to get mouse events has been answered yet.

Comment: That looks like a good alternative, haven't tested it so I don't know if it works for me. I did find the solution to the AttributeError: 'Rock' does not have attribute 'mask' (explained it in my answer below)    Thanks for helping anyways, if I run into anymore problems I'll try this method :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it working :)

If anyone else is trying to do something similar I'll explain here.

Put the below in your code (this solves the problem 'Rock has no attribute mask' error I got)

```
self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
```

Here is where I put it in my code (in my set_image def)

```
def set_image(self, filename = None):
    if (filename != None):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(filename).convert_alpha()
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
```

Now combine this code with Marius and it works perfectly!